# Custom Boot Logo Only Works On Shutdown

Tags: 12.04, boot, plymouth

For some reason my custom boot logo is only working on shutdown. When booting up, it just displays the standard purple Ubuntu screen with the orange dots.

Any ideas why this might be happening?

Thanks.

Comment: Please give more information on what you did. Otherwise we stay in the dark and can't help you.

Comment: how u changed your boot screen?

Answer (score 0):

Have you run:

```
sudo update-initramfs -u
```

After changing a plymouth script you must run the above in order for it to take affect during boot - otherwise you only see it on shutdown.

Comment: Unfortunately this didn't work but i have upgraded to Macbuntu which has cured the problem. Thanks.